# Regular expression grabs everything when capturing group doesn't exist

Tags: regex, r, data.table

I'm trying to utilize a regular expression capture group to strip out some particular text from a column.  One thing I noticed is if the capturing group does not exist, it grabs everything.

Here's the code I'm using to create a new column with the parsed text (data.table syntax in R):

```
regexp <- "(?:.*)([0-9]{2,3})(\\s?[Gg]?[Aa]?[Ll]?[Ll]?[Oo]?[Nn]?)(?:.*)"
data <- data[, Volume := gsub(regexp, "\\1\\2", Title)]
```

The data looks like:

```
Nice 55 g fish tank with stand  
45 Gallon Aquarium fish tank and Stand  
Amazing Hexagonal Fish Tank.  
92gallon fish tank  
Fish Tank & Stand $30 obo  
2007 PROLINE 29' GRAND SPORT CENTER CONSOLE
110 gallon tall fish tank  
20 and 10 Gallon Aquarium / Fish Tanks
```

The results look like:

```
55 g                            <- fine  
45 Gallon                       <- fine  
Amazing Hexagonal Fish Tank.    <- not good.  how to replace with NA?  
92gallon                        <- fine  
30 o                            <- wrongly identified  
29                              <- wrongly identified 
10 gallon                       <- I thought [0-9]{2,3} would grab 2 or 3 digits?  
10 gallon                       <- only 1 of 2 tank sizes identified
```

The goal is to pull the tank volume size out of the listing as best as possible. So a few questions:

1. Is this the best R function to do this task?  I was trying to stay within the base functions first, before installing a package.
2. If a 2 digit number doesn't exist in the text, the regular expression seems to pull in the entire text.  I'd like the "Amazing Hexagonal Fish Tank." to be NA.
3. There are a couple other things wrong if easy to fix, but main questions are the ones above.

I really appreciate the help!  I'd love to get better at regular expressions in R, but apparently it's a slow, dumb process for me.

Comment: *off-topic:* when assigning by reference (using `:=`), you don't have to assign the result back. That is, `data <- ` is redundant. Check the [Reference Semantics vignette here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Yea, I haven't thought much yet about the wrongly identified ones.. but NA would be preferable!

Comment: Why are you making each letter optional?

Comment: Just because sometimes people say 90g, 90gal, 90gallon, 90 g, etc.  I was trying to make the code smarter to pick up any of these variations.  But maybe I could make it so it only looks for a number followed by a "Gg" or " Gg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exact output you are expecting, but here is my attempt:

```
x <- c('Nice 55 g fish tank with stand', 
       '45 Gallon Aquarium fish tank and Stand',
       'Amazing Hexagonal Fish Tank.', 
       '92gallon fish tank', 'Fish Tank & Stand $30 obo',
       "2007 PROLINE 29' GRAND SPORT CENTER CONSOLE", 
       '110 gallon tall fish tank',
       '20 and 10 Gallon Aquarium / Fish Tanks')

r <- regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\d{2,3}[^\n]*(?i:g\\b|gallon)', x, perl=TRUE))
unlist({r[sapply(r, length)==0] <- NA; r})

# [1] "55 g"             "45 Gallon"        NA                 "92gallon"        
# [5] NA                 NA                 "110 gallon"       "20 and 10 Gallon"
```